# Is it possible to Import Data to a Multiple Choices Field Column in a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, choice-field, export-to-excel, excel-import

I am currently in the process of migrating data from a previous SharePoint list to a new SharePoint list outside our organization's network. One of the fields in the original list is multiple choice column labeled as "keywords". When I export it to excel, all the keywords export in one column separated by a comma.

With that said, when I import the data to a new SharePoint list, is there a way to get those keywords appear as multiple choices? Or do I have to manually enter them one-by-one? This is not ideal as there are around 500 items.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use save list as a template to migrate list data.

Reference:

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/save-list-as-a-template-in-sharepoint-2013/

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Awesome. I'll definitely try this out. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.